# Body in the water treatment plant, I don't see it

Tags: fallout-shelter

[image]

I'm playing Fallout Shelter and my dwellers see a body in the water treatment plant. They want me to get rid of it, but i don't see ANYTHING! What do I do?

Comment: Do you have a corpse elsewhere in the facility?  Back when I was playing, I seem to recall my dwellers making "delayed" comments like that, particularly if I was recently reassigning them between rooms and such.

Comment: No, there aren't any bodies anywhere in my shelter...

Answer (score 2):

This is a known glitch.

The only fix is to destroy the room and re-build it.

Comment: Has this happened to you before?

Comment: Yes.  I've had this happen before.